# Trouble connecting bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, 16.10, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and I'm having some trouble connecting my bluethooth headphones. At first I could connect them but couldn't choose them as my sound source, and didn't get any sound.
After I read some guides I can't even connect them and get a error message saying

> Setting up 'Bose QC35' failed

How can I fix this? I bumped in to several guides telling me to write

```
sudo aptitude install bluetooth pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

in the terminal but I only get

> Failure: Module initialisation failed

What to do with this failure?

**EDIT**

Yes my headphones was in pairing mode

output of terminal command:
➜  ~ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8170]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3b2 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b97:7772 O2 Micro, Inc. OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS Fingerprint sensor
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1199:9063 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: The `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` is loaded by default in 16.10. - no need to load it again. Did you put your headphones in **pairing mode** to then pair them before connecting?